# Getting error in Pubspec.yaml file and showing warning all over it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, jsonschema

My pubspec.yaml file is full of warning not running and showing me warning that: "Schema Validation: Missing required properties 'branches',upstream, inspection info:  Validates YAML file against a JSON Schema, if the is specified

[image: Yaml file]

Comment: VSCode automaticlaly identifies any files it recoginises, and applies the schema to check for validity. You can see the list of schemas at http://schemastore.org/json/ - It includes pubspec.yaml

Comment: It looks like you have a different schema selected at the bottom of the window... "backportrc.json", which would explain your errors. Did you manually change the schema?

Comment: no but i have backup of my project and i recreate it and error is resolved, but do you have any solution if i face it again?

Comment: If you can't reliably reproduce the problem, it's difficult for anyone to test a possible solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the **bottom right** there is Schema written...

```
Click on Schema and select **pubspec**.
```

That's all!